# output time format as "hh:mm:ss" in vb

Tags: vbscript

So I'm trying to convert some project of mine from excel `vba` to `vb`.
However I'm having difficulties when it comes to converting date and times stamps.

So: I have a number in seconds, i.e.: 3878, which I would like to display in `vb` as `"hh:mm:ss"`. in `VBA` I would use the function `.Format(time,"HH:MM:SS")`, however this is does not seem to work.

Any help on this would appreciated.

thanks 
Philippe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
intTotalSecs = 3878
MsgBox intTotalSecs & "(s) ===> " & ConvertTime(intTotalSecs),vbinformation,"output time format as hh:mm:ss"
'************************************************************
Function ConvertTime(intTotalSecs)
Dim intHours,intMinutes,intSeconds,Time
intHours = intTotalSecs \ 3600
intMinutes = (intTotalSecs Mod 3600) \ 60
intSeconds = intTotalSecs Mod 60
If intHours = 0 Then intHours = "0"&intHours 
If intMinutes = 0 Then intMinutes = "0"&intMinutes 
If intSeconds = 0 Then intSeconds = "0"&intSeconds 
ConvertTime = LPad(intHours) & " h : " & LPad(intMinutes) & " m : " & LPad(intSeconds) & " s"
End Function
'************************************************************
Function LPad(v) 
 LPad = Right("00" & v, 2) 
End Function
'************************************************************
```